# Async response from API Gateway in microservices

Tags: microservices

In microservice architecture, It is suggested that:

1. client app to API gateway communication should be synchronous (like
   REST over http).
2. API gateway to micro-service communication should also be
   synchronous
3. But service to service communication should be asynchronous.

> Another rule you should try to follow, as much as possible, is to use
>   only asynchronous messaging between the internal services, and to use
>   synchronous communication (such as HTTP) only from the client apps to
>   the front-end services (API Gateways plus the first level of
>   microservices).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/architect-microservice-container-applications/asynchronous-message-based-communication

Now, If I understood it right, when user requests to API gateway, and in turn it calls the fist service, it will return a acknowledgement (with some GUID) which will be passed to client application. But services will keep on executing the request. 
Now the question pop ups, how will they notify the client application when the request is processed completely. One way is that client can check the status using the GUID passed to it.

But can it be done with some push notification? How can we integrate server to server push notification?

Comment: That advice is false. It's impossible to give such a general guideline. The proper communication style depends on the specific circumstances of each individual communication path.

Comment: @usr, understood what you mean. This will depends on the use case. But lets assume that there is a scenario for this use case, what will be the solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I have little bit different understanding on this as it says communication between services should be asynchronous while communication to API gateway and API gateway to service should be rest API.
so we don't need to do anything as these are simple API calls and pipeline will handle request-response tracking while asynchronous calls between services will increase the throughput of the service.

Answer (score 0):

> Now, If I understood it right, when user requests to API gateway, and in turn it calls the fist service, it will return a acknowledgement (with some GUID) which will be passed to client application. But services will keep on executing the request.

No, the microservices should not continue to execute the request, it is already finished. They will, when it is required, update their internal cache (local representation to be more precise) of the needed remote data (data from the microservice that executed the request) when that remote data has changed. The best way to do that update is using integration events (i.e. when a microservice executes a request that mutates the data, it publishes an event to the subscribed microservices).

The microservices should not communicate not even asynchronously in order to fulfill a request from the gateway or clients. They should use background tasks to prepare the data ahead of time for when a request comes.

Comment: When I said "keep on executing", I mean service will call another service through middleware. For instance, client application hit the order service to place the order, order service acknowledge the order request and return the response (acknowledgement). And internally it check the inventory by passing the message to inventory service. So, this is processed asynchronously.  User request is already served. Once the inventory is checked, order service will confirm the order. Point is, how to communicate this confirmation to the client?

Comment: @Pragmatic so, the question is in fact "how to notify  the user about the status change of the *business process*?"

Comment: @Pragmatic you can return to the client an Url where it can poll for the process status or use Server sent events (SSE) between client and API gateway.

Comment: This what I was thinking, providing a url (and some GUID). Wondering, if we can notify app ourselves, or if client can expose any url that we can all once request is processed. I guess, calling client Url (something like webhook) seems to be a good choice,

Comment: @Pragmatic what do you mean exactly with "calling client Url"?

Comment: Client application will have a endpoint, which server application can call. For instance, jenkin provides an endpoint which can be called by bitbucket repository, whenever code is checked into the repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179379/discussion-between-constantin-galbenu-and-pragmatic).

Answer (score 0):

You're depicting a scenario where the whole interaction between the system and external actors (to be rude, the users) follows an asynchronous model. This is perfectly reasonable, but just if you really need it. Matter of fact, if you are choosing to let 'the outside' interact with your system through REST APIs, maybe you don't need it at all.

If the system receives requests through a synchronous application endpoint, such as REST endpoint, it has to complete requests before to send a response, otherwise it would be meaningless. consider an API like

POST users/:username/notifications

a notification is synchronous by it's nature, but the the request just states that 'a new notification should be appendend to the notifications collection of  user'. The API responds 201 that means 'ok, the notification is already associated with the user, it will be pushed on some channel, eventually'. This is a 'transactional' way to describe an asynchronous interaction

Another scenario comes when the user wants to subscribe the notification channel. I expect that this would be implemented with a bi-directional, asynchronous, pubsub communication protocol, such as websockets.

In both cases, however, doesn't matter how microservices communicate with each other, if the request is synchronous, the first service of 'the chain' should wait until is ready to respond. This is the reason beacause API gateway forwards the request in http.

On the other hand, aynchronous communication could be used to enforce consistency between services, instead of to make the actual communication. Let's say that  the Orders service sends data to a broker. each time some attribute on the orders[orderId] is changed, it published the change in /orders/:orderId topic. At the same time, expose an internal http point. each service caches data from the services which depends on. The user service make a GET /orders/:orderId , while sends a response to the requester, puts the data in a local cache and subscribes the orders/:orderId topic. each time that a 'mutation' is sent on this topic, the User service catches it and applies the mutation on the corresponding cached object. The communication is syncrhonous, keeps to be synchronous and it' relatively simple to manage; at the same time your system can hold replicated data and be still [eventually] consistent